# Invert the shadows of the button vertically

Tags: html, css

I have these beautiful push buttons:

```css
body {
  background: #555;
  padding: 100px 300px;
}

.level-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.level-buttons .pusher {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 15px 80px 12px 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cc0000 0%, #990000 100%);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 maroon;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), inset 0 3px 1px #ff1a1a, inset 0 9px 1px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  /* edge-highlight*/
}
.level-buttons .pusher:hover {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 65%, ellipse closest-corner, #e60000 0%, #cc0000 80%, #b30000 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.6), 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), inset 0 3px 1px #f50000, inset 0 9px 1px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 6px 3px 1px #990000;
  /* inner color*/
}
.level-buttons .pusher:active {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e60000 0%, #cc0000 80%, #b30000 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.4), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  /* edge-highlight 1*/
}
```

```html
<div class="level-buttons">
  <a href="#" class="pusher"> Pusher </a>
  <a href="#" class="pusher"> Pusher </a>
  <a href="#" class="pusher"> Pusher </a>
</div>
```

I tried to invert the shadows vertically in order to get the illusion we are looking at them from above with no luck!

How can we invert the shadows vertically in the proper way?

Edit: Here is what I mean by invert vertically:

[image]

Comment: It already looks like from above to me. The top is light and the shadow is below. Generally, invert shadows by using negative numbers.

Comment: If i understood correctly you are try to create button look like a switcher? [link](https://codepen.io/Homhing/pen/AuLKt)

Comment: yes............

Comment: For just invert, try the opposite offset-y for example `inset 0 -3px 1px #ff1a1a, inset 0 -9px 1px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)` in the *.level-buttons .pusher* class.